# When performing artificial insemination, why is the male donor tested for STD/HIV via blood test urine, instead of directly testing the semen?

Tags: hiv, std, artificial-insemination

https://www.thebodypro.com/article/hiv-can-be-found-in-semen-even-when-viral-load-is-:

> HIV can be detected in semen of men who have an undetectable viral load in blood, according to results of a 304-man study. This finding underlines the importance of using condoms when having sex, even if a man is taking antiretroviral therapy and has an undetectable viral load in blood.

When performing artificial insemination, why is the male donor tested for STD/HIV via blood test and urine, instead of directly testing the semen?

According to the quote above, the HIV tests seem more relevant when done directly on the seamen, and STD/HIV tests via blood test and urine aren't guaranteed to match the actual STD status at the time of the deposit (the male may have caught some STDs between the blood test date and the seamen deposit date, or the HIV may not show up on the blood test yet).

Comment: Did you notice that the article and all its citations are circa 2012 or earlier? Has more been learned since then that contradicts those studies?

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks, I hadn't noticed it, this is an interesting observation. I now wonder the same.

Comment: That would certainly be an area of the topic which would need to be covered in an answer to this question @CareyGregory

Comment: @ChrisRogers Or better yet, for OP to investigate and add to the question.